# Adobe AIR application to receive back events from native Windows application

Tags: apache-flex, interop, event-handling, mxml

I'm trying to develop a simple mxml Flex application to start Skype from the AIR/Flashplayer runtime. Is it possible to get back events from a native  Windows application? In the simple example of Skype, the OS returns control to the Flex app when Skype exits. But what about native applications which have their own event model and wants to communicate with the Flex event model. For example, a Face detection system which shows "Hello" on a Flex app when the camera detects a face. Can this be done in the current Flex framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use a NativeProcess to get data / info back from a native windows application.